# How to sort a text file by integers when the lines begin with strings?

Tags: python, python-2.7

How to sort a text file by integers when the lines begin with strings?

I would like to make this list

```
Adams   3.7
Alexander   36.1
Bond    6.5
Boone   2.6
Brown   19.1
Bureau  0.8
Calhoun     0.3
Carroll     1.1
Cass    4.4
Champaign   12.8
```

like

```
Calhoun     0.3
Bureau  0.8
Carroll     1.1
Boone   2.6
Adams   3.7
Cass    4.4
Bond    6.5
Champaign   12.8
Brown   19.1
Alexander   36.1
```

I also then plan on removing all lines with a value greater than 1, and then on removing all of the integers.

Comment: In order to get better answers, you should show what you tried.

Comment: you can create list of pairs(string, integer),  then sort this list by integer values

Answer (score 2):

```
# open file
with open("my_file.txt") as infile:
    # make a list with each line
    # split lines by whitespace, so that the name is element 0 and value is element 1
    file_lines = [line.split() for line in infile]

# sort lines, with the sort key being the value (element 1)
# we need to cast it to a float first, so that numeric comparison behaves correctly
sorted_lines = sorted(file_lines, key=lambda x:float(x[1]))
print(sorted_lines)
# [['Calhoun', '0.3'], ['Bureau', '0.8'], ['Carroll', '1.1'], ['Boone', '2.6'], ['Adams', '3.7'], ['Cass', '4.4'], ['Bond', '6.5'], ['Champaign', '12.8'], ['Brown', '19.1'], ['Alexander', '36.1']]

# export back to file in the same format
outfile_lines = ["\t".join(line) for line in sorted_lines]
with open("my_file_sorted.txt", "w") as outfile:
    outfile.writelines(outfile_lines)
```

You could later filter `sorted_lines` even further. For example:

```
filtered_lines = [line for line in file_lines
                     if float(line[1]) <= 1  # "remove all lines with value greater than 1"
                     and float(line[1]) != float(int(line[1]))  # "remove all of the integers"
                 ]
```

Comment: I'm getting ValueError: could not convert string to float at sorted_lines = sorted(file_lines, key=lambda x:float(x[1]))

Comment: It works with the data you gave in your question. If you have cases where the "name" is multiple words (e.g. "Mary Anne"), those would parse as separate tokens, and so trying to convert `"Anne"` to a float would yield that error. You could fix this by changing the `[1]` to `[-1]` (if the number is always going to be the last thing in the row), but it might still output the file wrong. A better way would be to change how you're reading in your information, so that the decimal number is always in its own token, and always at the same index of the list (which you can then use in the key).

Comment: I'm trying the filtered_lines code and I'm getting `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 0.9` at `and float(line[-1]) != float(int(line[-1]))`

Answer (score 0):

This will work!

```
fp = open('file')

pairs = [line.split() for line in fp]

fp.close()

# pair = [['Adams', '3.7'], ['Alexander', '36.1'], ['Bond', '6.5'], ['Boone', '2.6'], ['Brown', '19.1'],
#         ['Bureau', '0.8'], ['Calhoun', '0.3'], ['Carroll', '1.1'], ['Cass', '4.4'], ['Champaign', '12.8']]

pairs.sort(key=lambda item: float(item[1]))
print(pairs)
# pairs = [['Calhoun', '0.3'], ['Bureau', '0.8'], ['Carroll', '1.1'], ['Boone', '2.6'], ['Adams', '3.7'], ['Cass', '4.4'],
#          ['Bond', '6.5'], ['Champaign', '12.8'], ['Brown', '19.1'], ['Alexander', '36.1']]

fp = open('result', 'w')

for pair in pairs:
    string = str(pair[0]) + '   ' + str(pair[1]) + '\n'
    fp.write(string)

fp.close()
```

Comment: excellent. any chance you can tell me now how to remove the numbers from the result altogether?

Comment: you just want the list of names?

Comment: If so, then replace `string` line with `string = str(pair[0]) + '\n'`